# Not returning PDO object from custom database class

Tags: php, database, oop, model, pdo

I'm trying to create a database connection class that all my models will extend from.

the problem is, is that it isn't returning the database object even though I am telling it to return the PDO connection object:

`class Database {`

```
protected $conn ;
public $user ;
public $pass ;
public $database ;
public $encoding ;

function __construct($user = 'user', $pass = 'pass', $database = 'view4', $host = 'localhost', $encoding = 'UTF8')
{
    try {
        $this->user = $user ;
        $this->pass = $pass ;
        $this->database = $database ;
        $this->encoding = $encoding ;

        $options = array(
                   'PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE' => 'PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING',
                   'PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT' => TRUE,
                   'PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE' => 'PDO::FETCH_ASSOC',
                   'PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES' => FALSE,
                    ) ;

        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$this->database,
                              $this->user,
                              $this->pass,
                              $options
                             ) ;
        $this->conn->exec('SET NAMES '.$this->encoding) ;
        return $this->conn ;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->handleError($e) ;
    }
}

protected function handleError($e)
{
    if(strstr($e->getMessage(), 'SQLSTATE[')) { 
        preg_match('/SQLSTATE\[(\w+)\] \[(\w+)\] (.*)/', $e->getMessage(), $matches); 
        $code = ($matches[1] == 'HT000' ? $matches[2] : $matches[1]).': ';
        echo $message = $code.$matches[3] ;
        return false ;
    } 
}
```

}

It gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMS4\libs\Database.php on line 52
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you turn on PDO  extension on your server ?

Comment: And Database->query does exist ? Your error says undefined method

Comment: @vodich it does not exist but exists in PDO. So return $this->conn should contain query().

Comment: See answer below, move db operations from the constructor to another method and try to see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `return` anything from a constructor. When writing `new Database`, you get a `Database` object, regardless of what you're returning from the constructor.